# <QtWidgets> file not found after brew install qt5

Tags: qt5, qtwidgets

I have recently just installed qt5 through the command 'brew install qt5' on my terminal, but when I try run a programme I get this error:

```
In file included from albums.cpp:4:
./albums.hpp:6:10: fatal error: 'QtWidgets' file not found
#include <QtWidgets>
     ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [albums.o] Error 1
```

Any recommendations? And yes I have looked through answers from people which have had the same problem but none of them help.

Many Thanks

Comment: Please add also the **complete compiler command line**.

Answer (score 1):

- You're missing the line below in your .pro file (QT uppercase letters):

  ```
  QT += widgets
  ```